# Php mysql for desktop applications

Tags: php, mysql, desktop-application, php-gtk

This is my first post.

I know this topic has been discussed before in this forum, but since I couldnt find any new 
posts regarding this and I didnt quite find the answers I am looking for, I am posting the 
query here.

I have been looking around the web, to collect information about using php-mysql for 
desktop application. i have searched the web and done it more thoroughly in this forum.
I have collected things of interest and many things remain that I need to know.

What I came to know is that, desktop applications can be built with php.

i would like to keep the debates aside as to whether its the best combiantion for desktop 
application.

Now I have come across many frameworks/tools to do the job.

These are:

- php-gtk2
- php-winbinder
- appcelerator titanium desktop
- easyphp
- php-qt
- phpdock
- quickphp
- innosetup
- Open Application Framework
- silverlight
- adobe air
- RIA
- etc, etc

Now I mainly need to build a business accounting and maintenance application. It requires a 
database. Thus I have planned to do it in php-mysql.

Now my quesries are -

1. Does php-gtk2 support database handling?
2. Is it recommended to go for php-gtk2 since no update has been released for a long time?
3. Will php-webinder be better that php-gtk2?
4. People have suggested Appcelerator Titanium Desktop, but I cant seem to find any 
   documentation for desktop development. All are for mobile platform.
5. Which one should I go for windows binaries or browser based? I have an inclination for 
   browser based one.
6. Can I use css, javascript/jquery with these tools?
7. Maybe sometime in the future I need to use some kind of web service from this app, so will that be possible easily?

I will post further queries as I get along.

But please help me by answering these questions in a detailed manner, as the fate of the project depends on these questions.

Thank you.

Comment: Please try to ask only one question at a time.

Comment: http://www.nightrain.naetech.com/ is what you are looking for. Note you may have to compile PHP with MySQL modules. However... for a standalone desktop apps it is better to use SqLite instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does php-gtk2 support database handling?

No. It is a GUI extension. PHP supports database handling.

> Is it recommended to go for php-gtk2 since no update has been released for a long time?

Subjective.

> Will php-webinder be better that php-gtk2?

Subjective.

> People have suggested Appcelerator Titanium Desktop, but I cant seem to find any documentation for desktop development. All are for mobile platform.

It took me about a minute to find [the documentation for it](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Titanium+Desktop).

> Which one should I go for windows binaries or browser based?

Subjective

> Can I use css, javascript/jquery with these tools?

Depends on the tool.

> Maybe sometime in the future I need to use some kind of web service from this app, so will that be possible easily?

Possible? Yes.

Easily? That's a bit subjective. I'm not a fan of the APIs I've seen for PHP to make HTTP requests.